# android errors shows no such table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting **`error no such table not found`** in my project I used **2 database**. One is perfectly working but the other one shows error.

Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_ADDRESS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ADDRESS  + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_STATE + " TEXT," + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_ZIPCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_STREET + " TEXT," + KEY_DOOR + " TEXT,"+ ");";      
    try{
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ADDRESS);
    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I tried to insert an data using this code

```
public void addAddress(AddressList address)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_STATE, address.getState());
    values.put(KEY_CITY, address.getCity());
    values.put(KEY_ZIPCODE, address.getZipcode());
    values.put(KEY_STREET, address.getStreet());
    values.put(KEY_DOOR, address.getDoor());
    db.insert(TABLE_ADDRESS,null, values);

    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a extra `,` ( comma ) in your create table syntax after the last TEXT. You need to remove it because it is invalid as per create table's syntax.

use this

```
String CREATE_ADDRESS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ADDRESS  + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_STATE + " TEXT," + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_ZIPCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_STREET + " TEXT," + KEY_DOOR + " TEXT"+ ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your <kbd>DML</kbd> statement is incorrect and then your second table is not created. You have to remove last comma from statement that causes error. Behind last column at table cannot be comma because it's last column.

```
+ KEY_DOOR + " TEXT"+ ");
```

Comment: @user1758457 did you remove last comma?

Comment: the error occurs when the breaking point comes at  db.insert(TABLE_ADDRESS,null, values);

Comment: @user1758457 try to call explicit create statement not in onCreate() but for example after click on button.

Answer (score 0):

You have included `,` & `;` semicolon for the last column. Try to remove last `,` & `;` at the end may fix your error.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 String CREATE_ADDRESS = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ADDRESS  + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ KEY_STATE + " TEXT," + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_ZIPCODE + " TEXT," + KEY_STREET + " TEXT," + KEY_DOOR + "  TEXT" + ")";      
 try{
     db.execSQL(CREATE_ADDRESS);
 }catch (SQLException e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```